# Realm Swift in Xcode 10.2 - ERROR: Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I recently had to update to Xcode 10.2 since my iPhone automatically updated to iOS 12.2 and I have to use it for some in-app purchase testing.

The project uses Swift 4.2 and Realm.

I knew I had to update Realm so here is what I did...

1. Downloaded `realm-swift-3.14.1`
2. In Xcode, I replaced the frameworks with the latest from the download in my case the ones inside folder, `swift-10.2`.

**"In the past the Realm folders used to be labeled as the Swift version now they are labeled per the Xcode version"**

3. Compiled and then I got the following error.

> > Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler: /Users/userName/MyApp/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule

[image]

What am I missing?

What do I need to do to be able to use my Swift 4.2 project inside Xcode 10.2 and `RealmSwift`?

Is RealmSwift ready for Xcode 10.2?

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode, click on your `xcodeproj` file. 
Then on the left bar, choose the `target`. 
Now click to the `build setting` tab and look for the `Swift language version`.

Here you can change the swift version to select the 4.2 again.

[image: Swift Compiler Language menu]

Comment: I tried what you suggested but no luck, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

That error should only show if you were using a version built in older versions of Xcode (for instance, if you using Realm from `swift-10.1` directory). Try to remove any Realm frameworks you have from the project, clean the project, delete project's derived data directory, restart Xcode and then make sure to add both `Realm` and `RealmSwift` from the `swift-10.2` directory.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that what I'm trying to do, should work (in theory). I think I already tried what you suggest but I will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: @ ajeferson - I tried what you suggested a few times and I keep getting the same error. I noticed one thing, that when I drop `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` they don't get copied, they are added as referenced files even if I have the `Copy items as needed` checked. The funny thing is that if I create a brand new project and drop the`Realm .framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` files, they get copied and everything works fine. Any idea why they don't get copied? Could this be the possible cause?

Comment: Wow, that's even weirder. When you update Xcode to 10.2, did you also update to recommended build settings? That should definitely not be happening.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what build settings are referring to?  I just installed it and then I got asked if I wanted to install the developer tools or something like that, which I did, but that’s all I did.

Comment: Nah, never mind, that shouldn't be it. That's probably related to that copying stuff. Try the following: go back to your initial state (with Relm for Xcode 10.1); remove both Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework from Linked Frameworks and Libraries; Remove both frameworks from you project (select Move to trash when prompted); Add Realm for Xcode 10.2 frameworks.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and no luck, it still didn't copy the files and the error still there. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry then. I'm out of options here. If your code is open source I might be able to help, otherwise I can just wish the best of luck.